# How to get variable name from xml element using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I want to get the variable I will use from xml thru powershell. Please see my sample code below.

Powershell :

```
$Hostname = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem).name
$IPAddress = ((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]
$Date=Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

[xml]$ConfigFile = Get-Content "C:\Settings.xml"

Write-Host $ConfigFile.Management.Printme
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Management>
    <Printme>
        $Hostname | $IPAddress
    </Printme>
</Management>
```

This is a sample code only. I have 3 variable on my powershell and I want to get what variable to use from my xml file. Can you give me a hint on how I will do this. As you can see the result of my above code is `$Hostname | $IPAddress` text instead of the value of $Hostname and $IPAddress. Thank you.

I am thinking to use -split and put it on array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ExpandString function:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($configfile.Management.PrintMe)
```